# Making jquery plugins work after an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, dajaxice, dajax

It's gonna be a long post, but I really had enough of trying to fix this. I'm really looking for some help solving my case.

**First:**

`fade.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".gallery ul li img.a").fadeTo("slow", 0.5); // This sets the opacity of the thumbs to fade down to 30% when the page loads
$(".gallery ul li img.a").hover(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1.0); // This should set the opacity to 100% on hover
},function(){
    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.5); // This should set the opacity back to 30% on mouseout
});
});
```

The problem here is after the ajax call of the next page, the fade stops working. So what I did is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".gallery ul li img.a").fadeTo("slow", 0.5); // This sets the opacity of the thumbs to fade down to 30% when the page loads
$(".gallery ul li img.a").live("hover", function(){
    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1.0); // This should set the opacity to 100% on hover
},function(){
    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.5); // This should set the opacity back to 30% on mouseout
    });
});
```

But this will only work when I hover over the image then the image will fade out. If I do the same for `$(".gallery ul li img.a").fadeTo` to `.live(...)` nothing happens, it simply doesn't work.

- how can make this work even after an ajax call, which is supposed to fadeto when it loads then fadeout when i hover over it.

**Second:**

I have a small slider that slides up on the image, `slider.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //To switch directions up/down and left/right just place a "-" in front of the top/left attribute
//Full Caption Sliding (Hidden to Visible)
        $('.gallery li').hover(function(){
            $(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'106px'},{queue:false,duration:160});
        }, function() {
            $(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'153px'},{queue:false,duration:160});
        });
    });
```

I changed `$('.gallery li').hover(...)` to `$('.gallery li').live("hover", function(){...})` but still it didn't work. Also I used `.on` instead of `.live` because it's deprecated.

What am I doing wrong ? I'm not a client side dude, most of my work is server side. I just need to make these 2 plugins work after the AJAX call happens.

Ajax:

```
@dajaxice_register
def gallerypages(request, p):

try:
    page = int(p)
except:
    page = 1

items = gallerylist(page)
html = render_to_string('gallery_content.html',
                                {'items': items,}, 
                                context_instance = RequestContext(request))

dajax = Dajax()
dajax.assign('#gallery-content', 'innerHTML', html)
return dajax.json()
```

Edit2:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Dajaxice.gallery.gallerypages(Dajax.process, {'p': {{ items.previous_page_number }},})" class="btn_prev"><b>&lt;</b></a>
```

and

```
$(document).on("keydown", "#pagenumber", function(e)
    if ( e.which === 13 ) {
    Dajaxice.gallery.gallerypages(Dajax.process, {'p': this.value});
}});
```

Comment: What is the Ajax call doing exactly?

Comment: Sorry i didn't mention this, Ajax call will simply load the next page in the gallery, I have a list of images in a div.

Comment: Just rerun the fade.js stuff after the ajax call is done.

Comment: How to rerun it after the ajax call is done ? Just to point out I'm using Dajax not Ajax, it's Ajax for Django. It's a bit different, no if success or something. I'll check it out now if i can run a function after the call.

Comment: I would hope it has an event for that :)

Comment: If it doesn't have a success function, that's a pretty bad ajax library :)

Comment: You have a success function: `add_data(data,callback_function)` which: **Send data to the browser and call the callback_function with that data** https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajax/wiki

Comment: Your `live` method is correct. For initial images test this one: `$(".gallery").delegate("ul li img.a", "load", function () { $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.5); }` **OR** post your ajax call to help more.

Comment: @Javad_Amiry I just checked it out, not sure thought how to make it work. I'll post the ajax call now.

Comment: And where you fire the ajax call? -I mean the click event.

Comment: No solution yet, tried .delegate but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but test this stuff:

**JavaScript via jQuery**

```
var initFade = function() {
    $(".gallery ul li img.a").fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
}

// your custom callback method
var reBindStuffs = function(data) {
    Dajax.process(data);
    // rebind your jquery event handlers here... e.g.
    initFade();
};

$(document).ready(function(){

    // initial first time loaded fade
    initFade();

    // hover live binder
    $(".gallery ul li img.a").live("hover", function(){
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
    },function(){
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
    });

    // document keydown listener 
    $(document).on("keydown", "#pagenumber", function(e)
        if ( e.which === 13 ) {
        Dajaxice.gallery.gallerypages('reBindStuffs', {'p': this.value});
    }});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- a click listener -->
<a href="#" onclick="Dajaxice.gallery.gallerypages(reBindStuffs, {'p': {{ items.previous_page_number }},})" class="btn_prev"><b>&lt;</b></a>
```

Comment: I gave it try right now but it seems it didn't work, even dajax stopped working.

Comment: use `reBindStuffs` instead of `'reBindStuffs'` and test again

Comment: I really don't know how to thank you. I simply don't know. Thanks a lot for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You were headed in the right direction with `live`, but `live` is depreciated for the `on` event. With `on`, you can include the selector as one of the arguments. The initial jQuery selector is only the container of the objects you want to add handlers to.

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="sombutton"></div>
</div>

$( document ).ready( function() {
   $( '#content' ).on( 'click', '.somebutton', function() {
      alert( 'do something' );
   } );
} );
```

Now even if we replace the content within the `#conent` div, newly added content with the class `.somebutton` will also have a click handler attached.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if the `on` event works as expected if you are not using jQuery to add the content to your page. Perhaps try using jQuery to do you ajax and loading of content into a div.

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't have to pass a selector to `on()`. If you want to directly register a listener on an element you don't pass a selector. You pass a selector when you want a delegated event registration, which might be good for the OP in this case, although I really can't make sense of their code.

Answer (score 0):

What you mention is a big problem, I refresh by hand. But I also use the .ajaxcomplete functionality. It runs every after every Ajax query

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){ 
    // Carga tabs por defecto por clases.
    if (typeof jQuery.fn.wf_responsivetab == 'function')
    {
        if ($('#rbtt_1').length)
        {
            $('#rbtt_1').wf_responsivetab({text: '...',});
            $(window).on('resize', function() {$('#rbtt_1').wf_responsivetab({text: '...',});});
        }
    }
});
```