# How to call a function after dajax success?

Tags: ajax, django, callback, dajaxice

here is my call:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Dajaxice.news.newspages(Dajax.process, {'p': {{ items.previous_page_number }},})" >prev</a>
```

How can I call a javascript function, after the ajax call success?

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to the same problem... I need to call some js code after Dajax call success... If you ever find out how to do this. please do post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786717/making-jquery-plugins-work-after-an-ajax-call/11787862#11787862). Cheers.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function my_callback(data){
    Dajax.process(data);
    // call my functions...
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" onclick="Dajaxice.news.newspages(my_callback, {'p': {{ items.previous_page_number }},})" >prev</a>
```

Comment: The [Dajaxice documentation](http://docs.dajaxproject.com/dajaxice/create-my-first-dajaxice-function.html#invoque-it-from-your-js) agrees; probably the best place to start looking if you have other questions.